# `RelativeLayout` set in a `FrameLayout` is catching touch events from the entire `FrameLayout`

Tags: android, android-layout, touch

**EDIT:** I just realized that if I want to add buttons or anything below, I want to be able to drag on top of them. So maybe my solution would be changing the Z-Index of the cards so they can appear outside the `FrameLayout`?

---

I have a `FrameLayout` as such:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/stack"
    />
```

I put a `RelativeLayout` in it that contains some items, but has the formatting of so:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    >
```

The only reason I have my `FrameLayout` set to `match_parent` is because the user can drag the relative layout anywhere on the screen, and if the width and height of the `FrameLayout` are `wrap_content`, the `RelativeLayout` gets cropped when dragged. However, when leaving it as `match_parent` touching anywhere in the `FrameLayout` trigger's the `LinearLayout`'s touch event.

For context, I'm trying to display a stack of cards, each the same size, and let the user drag the top one off the screen one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding directly to the `RelativeLayout`. Unfortunately, when creating a class by hand some of the gravity settings were lost, so I did something like this:

```
    int size = ScreenMetricUtil.convertPixelToDp(getActivity().getBaseContext(), 300);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    card.setLayoutParams(params);

    container.addView(card); // add to LinearLayout
```

And my helper method ([source](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels)):

```
public static int convertPixelToDp(Context context, int pixels) {
    float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (pixels * density + 0.5f);
}
```